# How to fetch strings from list to TextBlock in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a simple quiz app, with multiple-choice questions....but I'm very new to WPDev. Any way, For the questions, I'd like to fetch the questions from a list to a TextBlock, and when the player answered, the next question is loaded. I don't know how.

Here is the current .cs file ;

```
namespace PhoneApp6
{
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            List<String> questions1 = new List<String>();
            questions1.Add("Q1");
            questions1.Add("Q2");
            questions1.Add("Q3");
            questions1.Add("Q4");
            questions1.Add("Q5");

        }
    }
}
```

see, I've made the list, now how do I fetch those questions to appear in the textblock I've made?

Answer (score 0):

You need to research MVVM. Basically you have a ViewModel that will supply the list. Then in your xaml, you can bind your textboxes to the list. Quick example from memory:

Xaml:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
    <ListView.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public List<string> Questions = new List<string> { "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" };
}
```

Of course MVVM goes way deeper than this and this just scratches the surface, but should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use The Visual Tree to achieve this.

 public List<Control> ChildrensList(DependencyObject parent)
        {
            List<Control> list = new List<Control>();

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent,i);

                if (child is Control)
                    list.Add(child as Control);

                list.AddRange(ChildrensList(child));
            }

            return list;
        }
```